# How to tell if button in collection view header is selected when populating collection view?

Tags: swift, button, header, collectionview

How do I tell if I button in the collection view header is selected when populating my collection view?  I have 2 tabs in the header which determine which data I populate the collection view with so I want to be able to switch the data and reload the collection view when the user selects a different tab.

some code from header class as requested...I don't see the point though it's just a button.  I want to see if this button is selected while populating the cells and cell count etc.

```
class UserSearchHeader: UICollectionReusableView {

@IBOutlet weak var friendsButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var peopleButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var customSlider: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.friendsButton.selected = true
    customSlider.layer.cornerRadius = customSlider.frame.height / 2

}

@IBAction func friendsButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.friendsButton.selected == false {
        self.friendsButton.selected = true
        self.peopleButton.selected = false
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customSlider.frame.origin.x = 0
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**UICollectionviewHeader + UI Button** 
UIcollectionviewHeader are using dequeueReusableSupplementaryView and for some reason it created a UIView Infront of every Headerview, this would block all gesture that are happening. the solution is to bring the view to front like so:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   self.bringSubview(toFront: friendsButton) // this depends on you .xib
}
```

this will solve your gesture issue.

**Theres Multiple way to Create a UIButton Action inside a CollectionViewHeader.**

- AddTarget (as Answered by @derdida)
- Drag and Drop Action In CollectionViewHeader Class.

**Add Target :-**(refer to derdida answer)
inside of **viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind**// ps: you need to register your CollectionView Class & Nib

1. Add Target to UIButton like so.

`header.friendsButton.tag = 0`
`header.friendsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.HeaderClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)`

2. Created the Function like so.

`@objc func HeaderClick1(_ sender : UIButton){ print("sender.tag \(sender.tag)") }//sender.tag 0`

**Drag and Drop Action In CollectionViewHeader Class.**
for this example i will used @Wayne Filkins Question.

1. Ctrl + Drag UIButton To Header Class
2. Select Connection Type to Action create the function like so

`@IBAction func friendsButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) { print("something from friendsButtonTapped") }`

and thats it.

but the  main key here is to get the view to be to front. used debug view hierarchy to know more.

Someone can fixed my code view please!

**Update Solution**

Using UIButtonSetOnClickListener.Swift and heres the code:

```
extension UIControl {
     func setOnClickListener(for controlEvents: UIControl.Event = .primaryActionTriggered, action: @escaping () -> ()) {
        removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
        let sleeve = ClosureSleeve(attachTo: self, closure: action)
        addTarget(sleeve, action: #selector(ClosureSleeve.invoke), for: 
 controlEvents)
     }
}
class ClosureSleeve {
     let closure: () -> ()

 init(attachTo: AnyObject, closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
    self.closure = closure
    objc_setAssociatedObject(attachTo, "[\(arc4random())]", self, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
 }

 @objc func invoke() {
     closure()
 }
}
```

Here how to used is:

**Add Target :-**(refer to derdida answer)
inside of **viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind**// ps: you need to register your CollectionView Class & Nib

```
    header.friendsButton.setOnClickListener {
        //put your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 delegate methods who are important to decide which items will be shown. For example:

You have 2 different items, they are populated in:

```
let items1 = [Item]()
let items2 = [Item]()
```

Then you have a variable, that holds which items should be shown:

```
let items1Shown:Bool = true
```

Now implement the delegate methods with something like:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if(items1Shown == true) {
      return items1.count
   } else {
      return items2.count
   }
}
```

And

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   var item:Item!

   if(items1Shown == true) {
      item =  items1[indexPath.row]
   } else {
      item =  items1[indexPath.row]
   }

   // format your cell 

}
```

And implement any button function

```
func ChangeItems() {
   if(items1Shown == true) {
      items1Shown = false
   } else {
      items1Shown = true
   }

   // reload your collectionView

   self.collectionView.reloadData()

}
```

**Edit:**

Why not giving your button a target? (Add this where you dequeue your headerView!)

```
headerView.friendsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewControllerWithFunction.cellButtonClick(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

// for example:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    headerView.friendsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewControllerWithFunction.cellButtonClick(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return headerView
}
```

// Class YourViewControllerWithFunction

```
func cellButtonClick(button: UIButton) {
    // you can do anything with that button now 
}
```

Comment: Yes i know that part, but I have a collection view "header" which has it's own class.  There are buttons in that header that I can't access from within "cellforitematindexpath".  I mean i'm assuming I can't access them, since they are in the header class.  It wouldn't let me connect the buttons to the UICollectionView class.

Comment: Please show some code of your header class and implementation.

Comment: I added the header class. Really straight forward. Header with a button.  Need to check if that button is selected, to decide which data to populate the collection view with.

Comment: @WayneFilkins ok now i understand. the real issue is it was a CollectionHeaderView. i tried to recreate the issue. this Solution only work with tableview cell,tableview header, collection item. but not on CollectionHeader. there will be an unknown UIview infront of the collectionHeaderview when i tried to view in the Exploded View. i still havent figure out how to do this

Comment: @WayneFilkins found the answer. you need to bring the view to front i already post an answer

Comment: @derdida This line saved me : headerView.friendsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewControllerWithFunction.cellButtonClick(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) thanks :)